# How to create sum column for certain rows in dynamic DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called 'data' that keeps getting appended to over time and then the AVG/STD gets recalculated and added on after (in the future it may be MONDAY, TUESDAY WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, AVERAGE,STD_DEV).

```
ID    MONDAY   TUESDAY    AVERAGE  STD_DEV
 a         1         2        ...      ...
 b         1         2        ...      ...
 c         1         2        ...      ...
```

I want to have columns dedicated to the sum of its counterpart for each column all the way through.

```
ID    MONDAY   TUESDAY    AVERAGE  STD_DEV     MONDAY_SUM   TUESDAY_SUM
 a         1         2        ...      ...              3             6
 b         1         2        ...      ...
 c         1         2        ...      ...
```

I already drop everything from AVERAGE column and on when first reading in the data so I can add on extra days then recalculate AVG,STD. How would I write code to get a sum column appended for each column between ID and AVERAGE for a growing/shrinking dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
df = df.join(df.loc[:,'ID':'AVERAGE'].iloc[:,1:-1].sum().to_frame().T.add_suffix('_sum'))
Out[206]: 
  ID  MONDAY  TUESDAY AVERAGE STD_DEV  MONDAY_sum  TUESDAY_sum
0  a       1        2     ...     ...         3.0          6.0
1  b       1        2     ...     ...         NaN          NaN
2  c       1        2     ...     ...         NaN          NaN
```

Comment: thanks! by the way, how would I divide all the new sums by some scalar? im trying to include a .div call in the one liner but it's getting very messy @BEN_YO

Comment: @stackoverflow I am not sure what you need ~ maybe you can open a new question ?